# Convergence divergence of one series from another

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ be sequence of real numbers. Which of following is true:

1. If $\sum a_n $converges then  $ \sum a_n^4$ converges
2. If $\sum |a_n| $ converges then $\sum a_n^2$ converges
3. If $\sum a_n $ diverges then $\sum a_n^3 $ diverges
4. If $\sum |a_n|$ diverges then $\sum a_n^2$ diverges.

In book correct option is 2. But I dont know how to do it. How to approach such generalized questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. False. $a_n = (-1)^n/n^{1/4}$ is a counter example.
2. True. If $\sum |a_n|$ converges then $a_n \to 0$ so $|a_n| \leq 1 \to a_n^2 \leq |a_n|$ for large enough $n$.
3. False. $a_n = 1/n$ is a counter-example.
4. False. $a_n = 1/n$ is a counter-example.

In general: if you think its false try to construct a counter-example. If you think its true or cannot construct a counter-example then try to prove that it is true.

Comment: Initially option 1 could also be proved as $|a_n| \lt 1 $for some n, and so $a_n^4 \le |$a_n| for large n.

Comment: Oh wow.  The similarity between your answer and mine is uncanny.

Comment: @User786 Note that for $1)$ $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum |a_n|$ does not converge so $a_n^4 \leq |a_n|$ (while true for large $n$) would not work.

Comment: @SammyBlack Same goes for the last answer - there are basically 3 identical answers:)

Comment: @Winther The only reason you can use the logic in 2. is because we have a test called "Comparison Convergence Test".

Comment: @SONTO That is not the only reason. I prefer the monotone convergence theorem: $\sum^N a_n^2$ is an increasing sequence bounded above by $\sum^\infty |a_n|$ and by MCT it therefore converges.

Comment: @Winther It is indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**First, counterexamples for false claims.**

**1.** Note that $a_n^4$ is always positive, so you can construct a counterexample with an alternating series:  $$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/4}}.$$

**3.** Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

**4.** Let $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

**Now, for the true claim.**

**2.** Suppose that $\sum |a_n|$ converges.  Then, $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Eventually, $|a_n| < 1$.  (There is some $N$ such that $|a_n| < 1$ for all $n \ge N$.)  Now, $a_n^2 = |a_n|^2 < |a_n|$, and so $\sum a_n^2$ converges by the Comparison Test.

Comment: Very clear and detailed answer ! Good job Sammy.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/4}}$ to answer 1.
- Notice that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges then $|a_n|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ and then there's $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $a^2_n\le |a_n|,\;\forall n\ge n_0$ (for 2.)
- Let $a_n=\frac1n$ to answer 3. and 4.